# events firing twice in jqWidgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jqwidget

Why is this event firing twice?

The workaround is to check for event.args, but the event still fires twice.

```js
$('#input').jqxInput({
  width: 200,
  height: 25
});

var changedCount = 0;
$('#input').on('change', function(event) {
  console.log("changed");
  console.log(event.args != undefined)
  changedCount++;
  $("#log").html("total times fired: " + changedCount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>

<input id="input">
<div id='log'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1bmj4kzc/1/)

Instead of **change** try **blur**.

```
var changedCount = 0;
$('#input').on('blur', function(event) {
  console.log("changed");
  console.log(event.args != undefined)
  changedCount++;
  $("#log").html("total times fired: " + changedCount);
});
```

Comment: that's not bad, but now the event will fire every time the user leaves the input field.

Comment: @MattJacobsen I have updated jsfiddle. Now it will fire if user leaves input with some value.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('#input').on('change', function(event) {
  if (!event.args) return;

  console.log("changed");
  console.log(event.args != undefined)
  changedCount++;
  $("#log").html("total times fired: " + changedCount);
});
```

Doing that you ensure that the jQWidgets custom event is raised, not the standard Javascript change event of INPUT tags.